# Mysql variable '@' not working with 'IF'

Tags: mysql, variables

I have a code like this

```
@tmp_doi := IF(value_doi_8>0,value_doi_8,(value_stok_calc*hari/value_cogs_calc))
```

and it didn't store the value of my result.

Is there something wrong with @ and 'IF'?

I've tried this too

```
@tmp_doi := (IF(value_doi_8>0,value_doi_8,(value_stok_calc*hari/value_cogs_calc)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SET`:

```
SET @tmp_doi := (IF(value_doi_8>0,value_doi_8,(value_stok_calc*hari/value_cogs_calc)))
```